# Windows 7 Taskbar Widget or Toolbar

Tags: windows, windows-7

My Lenovo laptop has two task bar type programs that show the network status and battery status. I have been trying to search for what these types of widgits are called.  Unfortuantly my google-foo is only returning results for minimizing programs to the system tray.

I am not even sure if these are system tray apps or taskbar apps. but either way, please help me find a API reference or even better a tutorial.

I want to make a Work Week Widgit, that displays the current work week number on this widget. I program mostly in python, but am willing to learn another language just to make this tool.

[image: Task Bar Widget]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are known as [Desktop Bands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also known as DeskBands. Note that Desktop Bands are [not recommended starting in Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511446.aspx#deskbands). Note also that since they are shell extensions, they must be written in native code.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should make a desktop widget, but I just want a quick glance for the information, not an extra click to show desktop.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, i think we can write shell extensions in managed code starting with .net4 because .net4 supports side-by-side?

Comment: No, there are other issues with the CLR that create problems with shell extensions. For example, the CLR pumps messages while waiting to acquire a lock, which shell extensions are in general not allowed to do.